# mono gtk# - hello world deploy to windows

Tags: windows, mono, gtk#

I have this really simple Hello World example i wrote on a linux host using Mono and gtk#. It simply shows a windows with a button. Now i tried to get the binary running on windows but failed. i installed the gtk# with the standalone installer from the mono homepage. when i start the application it failes due to:

> System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled: Unable to load DLL
>   'libglib-2.0-0.dll': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)   Source=glib-sharp

Any suggestions?
BR

Comment: I don't think the stand-alone installer installs everything, what was the installer you used?

Comment: Just a heads up: I am assuming you installed GTKSharp right before you tried executing it. I would try a reboot after installing GTKSharp. The issue is that the PATH environment variable set by GTKSharp isn't recognized yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need either to run your app via mono.exe or just add the mono.exe location to the PATH environment variable value. You can do that in run-time like that:

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dllDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + dllDirectory);
        Run();
    }

    private static void Run()
    {
        Gtk.Application.Init();
        Forms.Init();

        var app = new App();
        var window = new FormsWindow();
        window.LoadApplication(app);
        window.SetApplicationTitle("Game of Life");
        window.Show();

        Gtk.Application.Run();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I wonder if `SetDllDirectory()` API would work as well (since this is a Windows-only issue), it wouldn't terrible to use pinvoke for this situation.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to register the DLL 'libglib-2.0-0.dll' in Windows using `regsvr32 libglib-2.0-0.dll` from the command prompt. An alternative is to just package all the dependencies with your executable.

Hope this was helpful.

-Dave

Comment: libglib-2.0-0.dll is not a COM dll, so you cannot register it!